# Is there any workaround to get host_time in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I know there is a system function to get the host name - which returns the Server Name (Application server name in my case).

```
SELECT HOST_NAME()
```

Is there a similar function like HOST_TIME() to get the time of application server?
Or is there any workaround at database side to get the time of application server when a procedure is called?

Comment: What's wrong with `GETDATE()` and `SysDateTime()`?

Comment: They both give the database server time. What I am interested in is to somehow retrieve the Application server time when a procedure is invoked.(Database server and Application server are hosted in different time zones)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a database question to me. You should have the application pass along a timestamp along with whatever query is getting sent along to the database server.

If you must define this at the database level, why don't you simply add the time zone difference? I'm not sure where you're located, though here in the US if I had that issue I would simply do at GETDATE() and then use DATEADD to adjust to the timezone of the other table. The only thing which you would need to spend some time on would be what to do when the time changes (daylight savings time etc.). In my case, none of our users use our system at that hour, though that may be different in your case.

Good luck, and let us know what happens.